# Page not loading while recording application in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

While recording application in JMeter, page is not getting displayed.

For actual daily purpose loading in browser, application uses '**automatically detect setting**' (no proxies).

How to solve it?

(For recording localhost setting is used. Since there is no proxy command prompt method is not applicable)

If anybody came across this situation or has some other easy way to record other than Fiddler, Blazemeter or Badboy (since few issues while trying those also) please respond.

Also please suggest if there is anyway to get recording log from blazemeter extension for chrome  because application is getting recorded with that extension, but recording log is not available.

If at least log is available I can use jcorrelate with the jmx and log as inputs to create script.

Comment: please give some suggestion to record above scenario. whatever tried is updated in the question itself. So please suggest if anything else can be done.

Comment: what do you mean by "For recording localhost setting is used. Since there is no proxy command prompt method is not applicable" ? Can you reformulate it so it is more understandable ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below to record web application in your browser

1.Create a recording Template in JMeter.

2.Open [HTTP(s) Script reorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and give a port number which is not is use

3.Open your browser and setup proxy

(uncheck automatically detect setting) and set Proxy server with port mentioned in Jmeter script recorder)

4. If your web application uses https then you might need to install certificate generated by JMeter.

The article below explains the detailed steps to record an application using JMeter proxy server

[JMeter Proxy Recording](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-recording/)

Comment: This usual procedure is already tried. The problem is even if we use this method page is not loading while recording. Also the second method of proxy recording can't be used here since the app doesnt use any proxies.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert [BlazeMeter to jmx](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension#faq), just setup a Blazemeter account

> A Blazemeter account is required to convert the recording into a JMeter script (.jmx) file because this process is performed on the server side. Any Blazemeter account (free or paid) will suffice. Signing up for BlazeMeter is super fast and doesn’t require any sort of commitment or credit card.

[image]